# Opacity on hover of parent is being transfered to submenu; how to prevent this using CSS

Tags: css, navigation

Right now the parent menu has an opacity shift on hover, this is being transferred to the sub menu (current & previous) as well. I want the sub menu to have a clear background so that the opacity band of the parent is the only thing that is visible. Is there a way to use an li class for the submenu that makes it exempt from the li class that is governing the parent. I've been trying different things but can't seem to make it work properly.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kn4Jx/9/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <ul id="mainmenu">
        <li class="liHome">
            <a class="maintextcolour" href="#item-x1y1" id="Home" rel=
            "none">INFO</a>
        </li>

        <li class="liServices">
            <a class="maintextcolour" href="#item-x1y2" id="Services" rel=
            "SubMenuY2">EXHIBITIONS</a>

            <ul class="submenu" id="SubMenuY2">
                <li class="sub1">
                    <a class="maintextcolour" href="#">CURRENT</a>
                </li>

                <li class="sub1">
                    <a class="maintextcolour" href="#">PREVIOUS</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li id="liEnvironment">
            <a class="maintextcolour" href="#item-x1y3" id="Environment"
            rel="none">CV</a>
        </li>

        <li id="liCareer">
            <a class="maintextcolour" href="#item-x1y4" id="Career" rel=
            "none">NEWS</a>
        </li>

        <li id="liContact">
            <a class="maintextcolour" href="#item-x1y5" id="Contact" rel=
            "none">MORE</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
@charset  UTF-8;

/* CSS Document */
body {
    background-color: #666;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#mainmenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

#mainmenu li {
    clear: left;
    position: relative;
}

#mainmenu a {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#mainmenu li:hover a {
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-color: clear;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: none;
}

#mainmenu li.active a {
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-color: clear;
    width: 100%;
}

.submenu {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 135px;
    top: 0;
    width: auto;
}

#mainmenu li a:hover + .submenu,.submenu:hover {
    display: block;
}

.submenu li {
    display: inline-block;
    clear: none !important;
}

.submenu li a {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.maintextcolour {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.maintextcolour:hover {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #0FF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.headertext {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. You want the parent background to be visible, and the child's not? In your fiddle this works? Or do you want the submenu items to show a non-opacity-affected background? Or you want the parent's background to be hidden only where the submenu's items are?

Comment: I didn't really read your post, because its hella long, but i think you just need to use rgba instead of opacity

Comment: I want the submenu to have no opacity, right now there is opacity on the parent and child, which makes it look like a lighter grey on the child - i want it to be all the same grey. Does that make more sense...?

Comment: okay I figured it out by using: > li > a:hover     The problem now is that when I hover over the submenu the hover on the parent disappears, there must be a way to wrap the submenu with the parent?

Comment: Also I just realized I had the wrong jsfiddle link, so my question probably made no sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the updated [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/kn4Jx/12/). I have just added color to the following css:

```
#mainmenu > li:hover > a {
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-color:clear;
    color:#0fffff;
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
   width:100%;
   \
 opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: none;
}
```

Hope you want this.